# Java console running in a screen autostart on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, console, screen, autostart

[Ubuntu 14.04] I have a java console application, and I need to run all time (1st problem), as well as I can re-access the console whenever I want (2nd problem).

To solve the second problem, I use a screen, then run the jar file in it. So that I can re-attach the screen to access my console app.

I am now stuck with the 1st issue. I want to make the screen autostart with OS. Because I need the app running all time. Anyone give me an idea? I appreciate all your help. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE 11/17/2015:**
With @janos's help, it works fine except using @reboot. I tried crontab starting the script each 5 minutes and it worked fine. But when i replaced it with @reboot, it did not work anymore!

Finally I chose this solution: Create a screen with a particular name, then create a script sh file to check if the screen with that name existed or not. If not, then run the screen along with java file. Last, create a crontab to run the script each 1h.

Many thanks to @janos for your effort and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a program after system boot, use `@reboot` in your crontab:

```
@reboot /path/to/executable args
```

For more details, see this Ubuntu help page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

---

As per your comments, you seem to be having difficulty running Java + screen with cron. To help you debug, I suggest to create a custom configuration file for `screen`, let's call it `~/screen-debug`, with a content like this:

```
screen -t home
screen -t java bash -c 'java -jar ...; echo Press enter to exit; read'
```

And use a crontab line like this for testing:

```
*/5 * * * * screen -c ~/screen-debug -d -m -R java
```

What's happening here:

- Run the job every 5 minutes
- Use a specific screen configuration
- Start screen in detached mode
- Reuse the screen session named "java"

  - If a session with this name doesn't exist, it will create it
  - If a session with this name doesn't exist, it will reuse it (not start another screen)
- There will be two windows in the screen session:

  1. Labeled "home": a simple shell, as if you run `screen` in your home directory
  2. Labeled "java": the Java program, hopefully happily running. If not happily running, you should see the error message that should help you debug the problem, and a prompt to "Press enter to exit". When you press enter, the shell will terminate in this window.

Once you get this working, then you can replace `*/5 * * * *` with `@reboot`.

Comment: I run `crontab -e` then edit the file with this code:
`@reboot screen java -jar /mypath.jar myargs`, then i reboot the system and see nothing happen.

Comment: Do you have experience running commands with cron? It's known to be notoriously tricky. Instead of `@reboot`, if you use `*/5 * * * *` (run command every 5 minutes), or similar, does that work?

Comment: I tested `* * * * * "echo cron worked >> /mypath/test.txt"` and it worked fine!

Comment: Running `java` is typically more complicated than running a simple `echo`. Specific environment variable settings are often necessary, for example `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Try to get your Java program running with `* * * * *`. I suspect that if you can get that to work, then `@reboot` will work too.

Comment: The java command works fine if it's standalone. I just tried run `* * * * * screen` to start only a screen. But no screen started. Do you think that the problem is related to `screen` command in crontab?

Comment: `screen` is an interactive program. If you run just "screen" with cron and no parameters, it will exit immediately, as there is no `stdin`. To force `screen` to not exit, start in detached mode: `screen -d -m`. I added more debugging help in my post, see the update.

Comment: I have tried many ways. I created a start script file at usr/local/bin and it worked fine with both `* * * * *` and `*/5 * * * *`. Bit it did not work when I replace with @reboot.